# Minimization of Nonlinear equations

Tags: estimation, optimization

I am relatively new to R, so I apologize if my questions isn't expressed well, or if there is excessive detail. What I'm doing here is taking a naturally occurring gas isotope of C12 and C13 that is produced at a linear rate (P) at respective fractions (F12 and F13) that sums to 1. The two isotopic gases are then consumed at rates k12 for C13 and k13 for C13. I then want to solve for P and k12 using a minimization function.

The equations are:

Eqn 1:  conc.12 =  ((F12*P)/k12)-(((F12*P)/k12)-c12zero)exp(-k12(t-t0))

Eqn 2:  conc.13 = ((F13*P)/k13)-(((F13*P)/k13)-c13zero)exp(-k13(t-t0))

Eqn 3: Sum Square Error = sum(((conc.12-c12meas)/0.07)^2) +sum(((conc.13-c13meas)/0.07)^2)

conc.12 and conc.13 are the estimated concentrations of two isotopes at time t

c12meas and c13meas are the measured concentrations of two isotopes at time t

t0 is the initial time point

F12 and F13 are fractions that sum to 1

k12 and k13 are exponential decay coefficients for the two isotopes, with k13 = k12/1.06

P is a linear production rate of both 12CH4 and 13CH4

The data for a toy data set with known approximate parameters follow:

Time     c12meas       c13meas

1       109.7000      19.35660
2       118.9150      18.74356
3       127.6693      18.15943
4       135.9858      17.60285
5       143.8865      17.07253 
6       151.3922      16.56722
7       158.5226      16.08575
8       165.2964      15.62698
9       171.7316      15.18986
10      177.8450      14.77336
11      183.6528      14.37650
12      189.1701      13.99837
13      194.4116      13.63807
14      199.3911      13.29476
15      204.1215      12.96765
16      208.6154      12.65597
17      212.8847      12.35899
18      216.9404      12.07602
19      220.7934      11.80639
20      224.4537      11.54949

Note that the rows in reality are of equal length and the problem above has to do with pasting them in to the web portal.

1. I first tried to solve these equations with optim with the following code:

   ```
     error.func <- function (k12, P) {  
     t <- Time
     t0 <-Time[1]
     c12zero=c12meas[1]
     c13zero=c13meas[1]
     k13=k12/1.06
     F12=0.98
     F13=1-F12
     ratio.12<- (F12*P)/k12
     exp.12<- exp(-k12*(t-t0))
     conc.12<-ratio.12 - ((ratio.12-c12zero)*exp.12)
     ratio.13<- (F13*P)/k13
     exp.13<- exp(-k13*(t-t0))
     conc.13<- ratio.13 - ((ratio.13-c13zero)*exp.13)
     error <- sum(((conc.12-c12meas)/0.07)^2)
     +sum(((conc.13-c13meas)/0.07)^2)
     return (error)
       }
     fit.model <- optim(k12=.05, P = 15, error.func)
   ```

This is the error code in R:
"Error in optim(k12 = 0.05, P = 15, error.func) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In optim(k12 = 0.05, P = 15, error.func) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly"

My intepretation of this is that the optim function can't solve multiple equations at the same time, so I then tried the solnp function.

```
  isotopes2<- function(x) {
  t=Time
  t0<-Time[1]
  c12zero=c12meas[1]
  c13zero=c13meas[1]
  k13=x[1]/1.06
  F12=0.98
  F13=1-F12
  ratio.12<- (F12*x[2])/x[1]
  exp.12<- exp(-x[1]*(t-t0))
  conc.12<-ratio.12 - ((ratio.12-c12zero)*exp.12)
  ratio.13<- (F13*x[2])/k13
  exp.13<- exp(-k13*(t-t0))
  conc.13<- ratio.13 - ((ratio.13-c13zero)*exp.13)
    }

  error.func <- function (x) {
  t <- Time
  t0<-Time[1]
  c12zero=c12meas[1]
  c13zero=c13meas[1]
  k13=x[1]/1.06
  F12=0.98
  F13=1-F12
  ratio.12<- (F12*x[2])/x[1]
  exp.12<- exp(-x[1]*(t-t0))
  conc.12<-ratio.12 - ((ratio.12-c12zero)*exp.12)
  ratio.13<- (F13*x[2])/k13
  exp.13<- exp(-k13*(t-t0))
  conc.13<- ratio.13 - ((ratio.13-c13zero)*exp.13)
  error <- sum(((conc.12-c12meas)/0.07)^2)
  +sum(((conc.13-c13meas)/0.07)^2)
  return (error)
    }
  x0 <- c(0.05,15)
  constraint = c(0)
  fit <- solnp (x0, fun = isotopes2, eqfun = error.func, eqB=0)
```

I received the following error message:
"Error: 
solnp-->error: objective function returns value of length greater than 1!

Comment: No matter which optimizer you use, you need to crunch down your objective function so that it evaluates to a scalar, that is what the optimizer is trying to minimize. You can do this by adding all the squared error terms together in one objective function, possibly weighted by their importance if you are so inclined.

Comment: Is that what you've already done (equally weighted)? I'm not an R guy, but with solnp, it looks like you specified isotopes2 to be your objective function, which doesn't make any sense. And you specified error.func to be an equality constraint function,(i.e.to equal 0 exactly) which doesn't make sense. You want the objective function to be the sum of all squared errors, and you would not also specify anything on the separate equations. So you could probably use either optimizer if you get the objective function correct and the syntax correct.

Comment: On optim,I think maybe k12=.05, P = 15 is not specified correctly, and error.fucn winds up not being the 2nd function argument, interpreted as your objective function.  Or something along those lines.

Comment: I think you need the argument to error.func for use in optim be a vector, see the reference guide. And then c(0.5,15) for the first argument of optim. Then error.func will be the 2nd argument.of optim.

Comment: So (?) for optim, use the version of error.func you used for solnp.

Comment: I have tried to use the error.func in solnp for optim, and it gives the same error message, so that's not the problem. The equations do work in isolation, just not the optimization. That is,  the two error.func equations give the sum of square error for the input values (error in the equation).

I admit to being a bit clueless to how solnp works, despite spending quite a bit of time trying reading over anything I could find on it from the web.

Comment: You should show the code for exactly what you tried with optim.  Also show what you get when you call error.func on standalone basis.

Comment: First, I neglected to thank you for working on my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the error code running the second error.func (sorry, I should have given them different names) in optim: Error in optim(x = c(0.05, 15), error.func) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In optim(x = c(0.05, 15), error.func) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly

Comment: The answer to just running the error.func is: [1] 235849.9

Comment: I suggest you add an edit to your question, and cleanly post the new versions of whatever you tried. Otherwise, some little thing you did wrong may not be presented. Did you look at the examples in the reference page and try to imitate the syntax?